# NSString *text to NSString *icon?

Tags: cocoa, macos, menubar

I am making an app that is a standalone menu item and the basis for the code is sample code I found on a website. The sample code uses a number as the menu icon, but I want to change it to an image.

I want it to be like other apps where it shows `icon.png` when not clicked and `icon-active.png` when clicked.

The current code is this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
// Draw background if appropriate.
if (clicked) {
    [[NSColor selectedMenuItemColor] set];
    NSRectFill(rect);
}

// Draw some text, just to show how it's done.
NSString *text = @"3"; // whatever you want

NSColor *textColor = [NSColor controlTextColor];
if (clicked) {
    textColor = [NSColor selectedMenuItemTextColor];
}

NSFont *msgFont = [NSFont menuBarFontOfSize:15.0];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paraStyle setParagraphStyle:[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle]];
[paraStyle setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
[paraStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
NSMutableDictionary *msgAttrs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 msgFont, NSFontAttributeName,
                                 textColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                 paraStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                 nil];
[paraStyle release];

NSSize msgSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:msgAttrs];
NSRect msgRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, msgSize.width, msgSize.height);
msgRect.origin.x = ([self frame].size.width - msgSize.width) / 2.0;
msgRect.origin.y = ([self frame].size.height - msgSize.height) / 2.0;

[text drawInRect:msgRect withAttributes:msgAttrs];
}
```

Also, I found a post describing a method on how to do this, but it did not work for me. The url to that is this: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem/comment-page-1#comment-46501.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Your post's body seems entirely unrelated to its title.

Comment: Well as of now, the menu bar icon is a number. I want that to change to an icon but I'm not sure how to do it. I posted the code that draws the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `NSImage` and draw it where desired. For example:

```
NSString *name = clicked? @"icon-active" : @"icon";
NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:name];
NSPoint p = [self bounds].origin;
[image drawAtPoint:p fromRect:NSZeroRect
         operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
```

Comment: Okay, one problem. It's not switching to the second icon when it's clicked. It stays on the second icon, `: @"icon";` at all times.

Comment: @Charlie I assumed that, since your sample code was relying on this `clicked` boolean, I could, too. But it sounds like it's not actually being updated when the icon is clicked. There should be a way to get that information to update `clicked`; what kind of object does the `-drawRect:` code you posted belong to? Something like `clicked = [self isHighlighted]` might work if it's an `NSMenuItem` subclass.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the NO to a YES in this line (below the code I posted) `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];` However now a blue background shows behind the icon, which is why I set it to no. Is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: @Charlie: See the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSStatusItem/setHighlightMode: However, a menu item that does not highlight blue when you open its menu will look weird.

Comment: It's not an attached menu though. It's more of a tooltip: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem/. Also, this seems to be what I'm looking for `- (void)setHighlightMode:(BOOL)flag{
    
}` but what do I put in between that?

Comment: Charlie: You don't override it; you send that message to your status item.

Comment: @Peter What do you mean by that? I see that all the other `voids` have code in between them such as the one in your answer, so I would put already existing code in between the `- (void)setHighlightMode:(BOOL)flag{ }`?

Comment: @Charlie: Your use of “`voids`” doesn't make sense. `void` is a type. Its presence in the signature of `setHighlightMode:` is as the return type. You do not implement `setHighlightMode:` at all; it is already implemented, and you simply need to send that message to your status item.

Comment: @Peter Then how come the document you sent me uses void with the `setHighlightMode?` And would this work instead? `[NSStatusItem setHighlightMode:NO]`;

Comment: @Charlie: It doesn't “use void with the `setHighlightMode`”. That doesn't make sense. It shows the signature, which includes the return type, which is `void`. And no, that would not work. You need to send the message to your status item instance, not the NSStatusItem class.

Comment: @Peter - Okay, I think I understand the part about the void. When you say status item instance, do you mean the part that decides what happens when the menu bar button is clicked? Sorry you are working with such a noob at this.

Comment: @Charlie: It seems like you're confused about the syntax, so I suggest reading (or re-reading) the Objective-C Programming Language document: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ If you don't have a C background, you may also want to brush up on C first. Scott Stevenson's “Cocoa and Objective-C: Up and Running” gives a good condensation of what you need to know. Also worth reading (possibly even before Language) is “Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C”: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/

Answer (score 2):

If this is for a status item and you just want an icon with no programmatic drawing, drop the view and set the status item's `image` and `alternateImage`. The former is what the status item uses normally; the status item switches to the alternate image (if it has one) when the user opens its menu.

Comment: @Charlie Using the configuration points provided by the class is generally preferable to overriding superclass methods. If you are working with an `NSStatusItem`, then setting `image` and `alternateImage` would be much simpler than custom drawing. You might even be able to do it from Interface Builder.

Comment: Okay thank you for the tip! However I can't do anything in interface builder because the code I'm working with doesn't show. What I mean by that is that it's not a menubar item, but a tooltip of sorts.